# SwiftUI overlay deprecated alternatives

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to follow [this calculator tutorial](https://betterprogramming.pub/build-the-apple-calculator-in-swiftui-2fad61285dc8) but am running into several issues.  One of the issues is the use of the .overlay method.  I'm assuming it doesn't work because it is [deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/overlay(_:alignment:)), but  I can't figure out how to get the recommeded way or get anything else to work to solve it, so am reaching out for options.

Xcode 12.4
Target: iOS 14.4

Here is the code in that section:

```
struct CalculatorButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    
    var size: CGFloat
    var backgroundColor: Color
    var foregroundColor: Color
    var isWide: Bool = false
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
            configuration.label
                .font(.system(size: 32, weight: .medium))
                .frame(width: size, height: size)
                .frame(maxWidth: isWide ? .infinity : size, alignment: .leading)
                .background(backgroundColor)
                .foregroundColor(foregroundColor)
/*    //Commented out to compile
                .overlay( {
                    if configuration.isPressed {
                        Color(white: 1.0, opacity: 0.2)
                    }
                    )
                }
 */
            //.clipShape(Capsule())  //this makes circle buttons
        
    } //func
} //struct
```

I've tried commenting out that section which is the only way to have it compile, but then the button press action of showing a different color does not work.

Comment: Move `.foregroundColor(foregroundColor)` to either above `.overlay` or below the overlay's `}`

Comment: The original comment was edited as the .foregroundColor line incorrectly looked like it was part of the .overlay when I edited the code to show the error it was producing.  If not commented out, the error is 
Type '() -> ()' cannot conform to 'View'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols
Followed by:Required by instance method 'overlay(_:alignment:)' where 'Overlay' = '() -> ()'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overlay is not deprecated. Where did you read that. I think your problem is that you try to use the overlay function in a button style, which is not possible. You can only use it in a view. The error you wrote behind it, also states that.
I'm also not sure what you want to achieve, because doesn't it work correct if you just not use the overlay?

I get this button without the overlay. Is that what you need?
[image]

With the button style:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("1") {
                print("being pressed")
            }
            .buttonStyle(
                CalculatorButtonStyle(
                    size: 40,
                    backgroundColor: .cyan,
                    foregroundColor: .black
                )
            )
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

I also added the changed button style.

```
import SwiftUI

struct CalculatorButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    
    var size: CGFloat
    var backgroundColor: Color
    var foregroundColor: Color
    var isWide: Bool = false
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .font(.system(size: 32, weight: .medium))
            .frame(width: size, height: size)
            .frame(maxWidth: isWide ? .infinity : size, alignment: .leading)
            .background(backgroundColor)
            .foregroundColor(configuration.isPressed ? Color(white: 1.0, opacity: 0.2) : foregroundColor)
            .clipShape(Capsule())  //this makes circle buttons
        
    }
}
```

Comment: It shows the button, but when you press it, it does not show the different color indicating it is being pressed.  Then returns the original color when button press is released.

Comment: Look at the altered button style code. It works fine in my example.

Comment: That worked beautifully, and is easier to follow than the original.

Comment: Cn you then, please, mark my answer as the correct one?

Comment: “Overlay is not deprecated. Where did you read that.”—You can read it [here, for the version of `overlay` that is deprecated](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/overlay(_:alignment:)). It was replaced by [a newer version of `overlay`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/overlay(alignment:content:)).

Answer (score 0):

An `overlay` is not needed. Take advantage of the `isPressed` value of the `configuration` to change the color

```
struct CalculatorButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    
    var size: CGFloat
    var backgroundColor: Color
    var foregroundColor: Color
    var isWide: Bool = false
    
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .font(.system(size: 32, weight: .medium))
            .frame(width: size, height: size)
            .frame(maxWidth: isWide ? .infinity : size, alignment: .leading)
            .background(backgroundColor)
            .foregroundColor(configuration.isPressed  
                      ? Color(white: 1.0, opacity: 0.5)
                      : foregroundColor)
            .clipShape(Capsule())
    } //func
} //struct
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two stray parentheses:

```
            // Remove this
            //      ↓
            .overlay( {
                if configuration.isPressed {
                    Color(white: 1.0, opacity: 0.2)
                }
                ) // ← Remove this
            }
```

The stray left parenthesis (the one immediately after `.overlay`) prevents Swift from recognizing the trailing closure syntax and makes Swift think you are trying to use the [deprecated version of `overlay`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/overlay(_:alignment:)).

The stray right parenthesis is improperly nested relative to the right-brace on the following line.

If you copy and paste the code from the tutorial, or if you remove those two  parentheses, the code compiles:

```
struct CalculatorButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {

    var size: CGFloat
    var backgroundColor: Color
    var foregroundColor: Color
    var isWide: Bool = false

    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .font(.system(size: 32, weight: .medium))
            .frame(width: size, height: size)
            .frame(maxWidth: isWide ? .infinity : size, alignment: .leading)
            .background(backgroundColor)
            .foregroundColor(foregroundColor)
            .overlay {
                if configuration.isPressed {
                    Color(white: 1.0, opacity: 0.2)
                }
            }
            .clipShape(Capsule())
    }
}
```